# select option (html 5 tag) position over next input (html 5 tag) in IE 10, 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

I have drop down select --> option "id="select_proptype" whose values are dynamically generating in jquery function... i have other select---> options are as well but the dynamic select position comes on top of following input (html 5) tag... this behaviour is only in IE 10 and IE 9 ....

here is my code ....

```
<div class="criteria_block">
    <span><label class="search_form_Label" for="proptype">Property Type</label></span>
    <span><select class="inputStyle_class" id="select_proptype" name="type" style="width:165px;"></select></span>
</div>

<div class="criteria_block">
    <span><label class="search_form_Label default_font" for="postcodes">Post Codes</label></span>
    <span><input class="inputStyle_class form_search_textbox" id="postcodes" style="width:160px;" name="postcodes" type="text" /></span>
</div>
```

in html i am calling function to get all values...

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

          $(this).SearchForm();
     });
```

jquery plugin function ..........

```
  $.fn.SearchForm = function () {
       //process the code//
       //generate option values 
     for (var val in plugin_Global_Variables.F_property_Type) {
      $("#select_proptype").append('<option value="' + plugin_Global_Variables.F_property_Type[val] + '">' + plugin_Global_Variables.F_property_Type[val] + '</option>');
  }
}
```

css----------------

```
   .criteria_block {
        display:block;
        width:300px;
        height:40px;
        margin-top:10px;
        color:#4E4E4E;
        border:thin;
        border-color:grey;
    }

    .search_form_Label {
        display:inline-block;
        width:100px;
        font-weight:500;
        margin-left:10px;
        line-height:40px;
   }
```

Comment: You really need to be clearer in your problem, what's the expected output? How are you updating the select options? etc

Comment: i have update my question.... my apologizes my incomplete question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the width in your css for .search_form_Label is set to 100px where has you label

```
 <span><label class="search_form_Label" for="proptype">Property Type</label></span>
```

need more width to display "Property Type" in once line that is why your select option position over the following input tag...

change your width to 100px+ to fit within frame....

```
 .search_form_Label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;             // change width here to 100px +
    font-weight:500;
    margin-left:10px;
    line-height:40px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.append()` to add the content - this adds the code you wrote to the beginning of the `<select>` element.

What you're looking for is either to replace the entire set of items by just replacing the whole html like so:

```
$("#select_proptype").html('<option value="' + plugin_Global_Variables.F_property_Type[val] + '">' + plugin_Global_Variables.F_property_Type[val] + '</option>');
```

Or maybe replacing just one option all the time, in which case you'll need to identify it somehow (either have an ID for it like so:)

```
$("#select_proptype").append('<option id="dynamicoption" value="' + plugin_Global_Variables.F_property_Type[val] + '">' + plugin_Global_Variables.F_property_Type[val] + '</option>');
```

and then replace that every time:

```
$('#dynamicoption').remove();
$('#select_proptype').append('...');
```

or simply replace it like this if you know it's always the first in the list:

```
$('#select_proptype option:first').remove();
$('#select_proptype').append('...');
```

Comment: i think problem is somewhere else !!! i have disable all dynamic code put hard code option values in select tag, and is still same behavior!!!